# How to Add Desktop Version and Mobile Version Link?

Tags: theme

I have added theme Exception for mobile user in System >> Configuration >> GENERAL >> Design.

And I want to add desktop version and mobile version link so the user can switch it.

I have no idea how to do this. Tell me where to start to make this feature?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9794/magento-design-exceptions-switching-back-to-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below code in action to set Package and theme for the action

```
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
->setPackageName('default') //Name of Package
->setTheme('modern'); // Name of theme
```

Comment: Thank you roshan for your help. But what file I need to add the above code?

Comment: Create a controller action and there you can put this code. Create a form that will switch theme on button click.

Comment: Thank you Roshan, it works. I start my project with this code :)

Answer (score 0):

Magento mobile theme works by detecting user-agent of browser. Please refer this link - http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/280148/#t418581

Comment: Thank roshan lal for your response. But I don't want to make new store view to do this.

Comment: Well then would you try changing user-agent of browser on button click. http://hynchrstn.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/make-custom-javascript-navigator-useragent/

Comment: @Wakanina - Did you get any solution?

Comment: Sorry for the late Roshan. My PC was crashed yesterday. Thanks, I will try it. I will update this thread when it success.