# Magento Design Exceptions - switching back to desktop

Tags: magento-enterprise, theme, controllers, mobile

I am using Magento's design exceptions to set the theme as mobile for mobile devices.

[image]

Since I am not using a separate store view or website, is it possible to provide to the user a 'Switch to Desktop' link? I guess I would need to override a controller somewhere, would appreciate anyone that can help me out with a starting point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer here is no, though, you *could* drop a javascript cookie called `forcedesktop` and set it to true. This would be set onclick for the switcher link.

Then rewrite the design exception method to sniff for existence of the cookie:

**app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_YourModule>
             <version>0.1.0</version>
        </YourCompany_YourModule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <design_package>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Design_Package</design_package>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Design/Package.php**

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Design_Package extends Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package
{

    protected function _checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps($regexpsConfigPath)
    {
        if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('forcedesktop')=='true'){
            return false;
        }

        parent::_checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps($regexpsConfigPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: will try it out, cheers.

Comment: This answer is correct, though there is a return missing before the `parent::_checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps($regexpsConfigPath);`. Otherwhise it would always show the desktop version when the cookie isn't set.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier this year we put together a quick module to implement this functionality complete with support for use behind the Enterprise Edition FPC. Since then it's been used on a number of sites we've built. When I saw this question posted I decided to polish it up and publish it on GitHub. @philwinkle beat me to posting an answer though... ;) And it does actually use the same basic technique he mentions. I.e. it sets a cookie which is then used to determine if the design exception should be honored or not.

In this case we are using `setcookie` and `$_COOKIE` directly for performance and/or compatibility with the FPC processor which EE uses on a cache hit:

```
class CLS_DesignSwitcher_Model_Core_Design_Package extends Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package
{
    /**
     * Get regex rules from config and check user-agent against them. We override to
     * determine if the design exception should be ignored based on presence of a cookie.
     * 
     * @param string $regexpsConfigPath
     * @return mixed
     * @see Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package
     */
    protected function _checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps($regexpsConfigPath)
    {
        $ignoreException = null;
        if (isset($_COOKIE[CLS_DesignSwitcher_Helper_Data::FULL_SITE_COOKIE])) {
            $ignoreException = $_COOKIE[CLS_DesignSwitcher_Helper_Data::FULL_SITE_COOKIE];
        }
        return $ignoreException ? false : parent::_checkUserAgentAgainstRegexps($regexpsConfigPath);
    }
}
```

I'll spare posting the full code for it here, but feel free to take it and use it verbatim or alter to suite what you need… You can grab a copy from here: https://github.com/davidalger/CLS_DesignSwitcher.

Comment: I used CLS_DesignSwitcher...But it shows error like " <b>Fatal error</b>:  Class 'Mage_Cls_Designswitcher_Helper_Data' not found "